# New to Programming it should refresh the site but it wont thanks

Tags: powershell

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$edge = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows()| ? { $_.Name -like "*Microsoft Edge*" }

while(1) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    try{
    $edge.Refresh() 
    } catch { exit } 
}
```

Comment: You should start with verifying the very first operation works.  Do you see anything when you run this command alone?  `(New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows()`.  I do not, and until you do, the rest of the code won't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work. Consider using the [Microsoft Edge Driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) if you need to do more advanced automation.

```
$proc = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("msedge.exe", "https://www.stackoverflow.com") | Get-Process
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

while ($true) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    $wshell.AppActivate($proc.Id)
    $wshell.SendKeys("{F5}")
}
```